# Clickable Pie chart to select data for bar chart

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, nvd3.js, rcharts

I would like to show pie charts for a number of years, with users able to click on one of the slices to select a single category to graph in a bar chart, in order to more easily see the year to year change for that category. Clicking on a slice would effectively do the job that selectInput is doing in the following script:

```
library(rCharts)
library(shiny)

Year1 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
Year2 <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
Year3 <- c(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5)
data <- data.frame(Year1,Year2,Year3)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    showOutput("p1", lib = "nvd3"),
    showOutput("p2", lib = "nvd3"),
    showOutput("p3", lib = "nvd3"),
    selectInput("selected","Select group to graph:",
                choices = c(1:5),
                multiple = FALSE,
                selected = 1),
    showOutput("bar", lib = "highcharts")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$p1 <- renderChart2({
      nPlot(~ Year1, data = data, type = 'pieChart')
    })

    output$p2 <- renderChart2({
      nPlot(~ Year2, data = data, type = 'pieChart')
    })

    output$p3 <- renderChart2({
      nPlot(~ Year3, data = data, type = 'pieChart')
    })

    data2 <- reactive({
      data.frame(Year1 = as.data.frame(table(data$Year1))[input$selected,2],
                 Year2 = as.data.frame(table(data$Year2))[input$selected,2],
                 Year3 = as.data.frame(table(data$Year3))[input$selected,2]
      )
    })

    output$bar <- renderChart2({
      a <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
      a$chart(type = "column")
      a$title(text = "Bar Chart")
      a$xAxis(title = list(text = "Yearly Data"))
      a$yAxis(title = list(text = "Count"))
      a$data(data2())
      a
    })    
  }
)
```

Any help is much appreciated. I'm not averse to using other packages, if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: you dont seem to be using plyr, dplyr, or magrittr. why are those libraries loaded

Comment: I was using them at first, when I was setting up the script with a different data set. Then I decided it was more straightforward to just build my data frame directly, but I neglected to go back and remove them from the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409466/add-unique-links-to-all-data-points-in-graph-with-rCharts), you could add a custom tooltip function that adds a click event when you click on a pie:

```
tooltip_function="#! function(key, x, y, e ){ 
                        d3.selectAll('[class*=\"nv-slice\"]').on('click',function(){
                        Shiny.onInputChange('selected_cat',key)})
                        return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' + '<p>'+ x +'</p>' 
                } !#"
```

The `Shiny.onInputChange` binds `selected_cat` to the value of `key`, which is the name of the pie the user clicked on. You can then use `input$selected_cat` to get that value in `server.R`.

The `renderChart2` need to be modified to add the tooltip function like so (example for the first one):

```
 output$p1 <- renderChart2({
                        n1 <- nPlot(~ Year1, data = data, type = 'pieChart')
                        n1$chart(tooltipContent = tooltip_function)
                        n1
                })
```

And the `data2`:

```
 data2 <- reactive({
                        data.frame(Year1 = as.data.frame(table(data$Year1))[input$selected_cat,2],
                                   Year2 = as.data.frame(table(data$Year2))[input$selected_cat,2],
                                   Year3 = as.data.frame(table(data$Year3))[input$selected_cat,2]
                        )
                })
```